# CamlQuery Recursive Search Under Specific Parent Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query

I am trying to recursively search all folders and files under a specified folder for given text.  For example sake, lets say my file directory is as follows-

**/sites/UsersTeam/Shared Documents/Folder A/Folder AA/Folder AAA/**

I would like to recursively search for all files, within all folders, under **Folder AAA** containing a given string.

When I use

```
<View Scope = RecursiveAll>
```

in conjunction with

```
camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = parentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
```

I would expect to only recursively search everything under **Folder AAA** (assuming my parentFolder is passed as Folder AAA), but it seems it's recursively searching all folders and files below **UsersTeam** folder.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Here's my function -

```
public List<SP.File> GetFilesFromParentUsingCamlQuery(Folder parentFolder, List<string> criteria, List<SP.File> relativeFilePaths)
{
    _clientContext.Load(parentFolder, p => p.ServerRelativeUrl);
    _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    SP.CamlQuery camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery()
    {
        ViewXml =                                    
                            $@"""<View Scope=RecursiveAll>
                                <Query>
                                    <Where>
                                        <Contains>
                                            <FieldRef Name='FileRef'/>
                                            <Value Type='Text'>TestFileName.xlsx</Value>
                                        </Contains>
                                    </Where>
                                </Query>
                            </View>"""
    };
    camlQuery.AllowIncrementalResults = true;
    camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = parentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;

    var docLib = _web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
    ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;
    do
    {
        camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
        var results = docLib.GetItems(camlQuery);
        _clientContext.Load(results);
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        position = results.ListItemCollectionPosition;
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            _clientContext.Load(item.File, f => f.ServerRelativePath);
            _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            relativeFilePaths.Add(item.File);
            Console.WriteLine(relativeFilePaths.Last().ServerRelativePath.DecodedUrl);
        }
    } while (position != null);

    return relativeFilePaths.ToList();
}
```

And here's the exception I'm getting:

```
The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.
```